# Time (HH:MM:SS) in plotly.js y axis is not plotted properly

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly.js

I am trying to plot a Time (HH:MM:SS) on y-axis  against days using plotly.js. The chart plotted is not properly sorted. Can anyone please guide what I am doing wrong. I have attached my codepen link here

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/chintzs/pen/eYmVLGQ)

HTML

```
    <head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
Plotly.d3.csv("xyz.csv", function(err, rows){
var trace1 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  x:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53],
  y: ["08:15:00","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:31:00","08:23:00","08:35:00","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:26:45","08:19:20","08:06:00","08:06:00","08:20:00","08:17:22","08:18:14","08:18:00","08:09:00","08:32:00","08:16:20","08:14:29","08:14:31","08:32:00","08:39:00","08:29:00","08:27:00","08:28:00","08:24:00","08:09:00","08:32:00","08:16:20","08:14:29","08:14:31","08:32:00","08:39:00","08:29:00","08:27:00","08:28:00","08:24:00","08:25:00","08:26:45","08:19:20","08:06:00","08:06:00","08:20:00","08:17:22","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:31:00"],
  name: 'Time In',
  line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Attendance',
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can't just use time alone, it needs a date too.

So I added a dummy date to the beginning of each time with `.map(time => '2020-01-08 ' + time)` and hid it from the axis ticks with `yaxis: { tickformat: '%H:%M:%S' }`.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var trace1 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "markers",
  x:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53],
  y: ["08:15:00","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:31:00","08:23:00","08:35:00","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:26:45","08:19:20","08:06:00","08:06:00","08:20:00","08:17:22","08:18:14","08:18:00","08:09:00","08:32:00","08:16:20","08:14:29","08:14:31","08:32:00","08:39:00","08:29:00","08:27:00","08:28:00","08:24:00","08:09:00","08:32:00","08:16:20","08:14:29","08:14:31","08:32:00","08:39:00","08:29:00","08:27:00","08:28:00","08:24:00","08:25:00","08:26:45","08:19:20","08:06:00","08:06:00","08:20:00","08:17:22","08:18:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:25:00","08:06:00","08:31:00"].map(time => '2020-01-08 ' + time),
  name: 'Time In',
  line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Attendance',
  yaxis: {
      tickformat: '%H:%M:%S'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```